# What would be the collective noun for collection of words whose affixal markers indicate the same grammatical categories?

Tags: terminology, morphology, linguistic-typology, inflection

I am working on Sanskrit, a fusional language. I am confused about what should be the collective noun that I should be used to address the set {nominals, verb, adverb, indeclinable, participle}. Could they be called as word class, inflectional class or morphological class or is it something completely different?

If there are multiple accepted nouns for the collection, which one would be more specific to a fusional language?

Here, I am not making a distinction between a noun and adjective because in Sanskrit, both nouns and adjectives have the same inflectional information, i.e. case, gender, and number. Summarily, a nominal is a collection of words whose affixal markers indicate case, gender, number.

So in a fusional language, if I group all the valid morphological tags based on the grammatical categories present in them, what should it be collectively called?

Comment: Usually the term [_part of speech_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) is used: “a **part of speech** is a category of words (or, more generally, of lexical items) that have similar grammatical properties.”

Comment: Does lexical category fit as a proper term?